# communicate() causes subprocess to fail - why?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am calling a java app from python like so:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["java", "-jar", "application.jar", "-o", "/path/to/outfile", "/path/to/infile"])
```

When the child process silently runs silently in the background like above, this works as expected (the application generates files and those contain what they should).

I however would like for one the process to be blocking and for another to catch it's output.

Hence the following approach:

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ["java", "-jar", "application.jar", "-o", "/path/to/outfile", "/path/to/infile"],
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    pstdout, pstderr = proc.communicate()
    if pstderr:
        raise Exception("Some exception")
    else:
        print "done"
except:
    print "FAILED"
```

This fails (previously successfully generated files are 0-byte) - even though the `Popen` args are exactly the same.

Without the `try ... except` and conditional

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["java", "-jar", "application.jar", "-o", "/path/to/outfile", "/path/to/infile"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.communicate() #prints java exception
```

it still fails.
The exception printed by `print proc.communicate()` is a Java `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, in case it makes a difference.
While removing the call to `communicate()` makes it execute as planned again:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["java", "-jar", "application.jar", "-o", "/path/to/outfile", "/path/to/infile"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE) # runs just fine
```

---

**Further Info (Edit)**
The java app in question is [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/), Yahoo's CSS and JS compression tool.

And in case it does help for shedding light, the full stack trace from java as piped to python and contained in `psterr` in the above second code block:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -860
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:908)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.substring(StringBuffer.java:482)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.CssCompressor.compress(CssCompressor.java:126)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor.main(YUICompressor.java:211)
    ... 5 more
```

---

**TL;DR**
While I am calling `communicate()` only in order to catch output, it somehow also sends garbage to the child process making it fail.
Why is that the case?

I assume this is because the java app still reads from `stdin` while `communicate()` sends it `EOF` in between.
How can I achieve the same functionality without sending `EOF`?

I could let the process simply run silently in the background, but I'd prefer a solution that allows for it to be blocking and me to catch output.
Is there a workaround around this obstacle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the first command works? do you call `proc.wait()` later? What happens if you run the same command in the shell with stdout/stderr redirected e.g., in bash: `java ... |& tee -a java.log`? Unrelated: don't use a bare `except:` here. Post the full traceback.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, I am certain the first (and last) command works. No I don't call `proc.wait()` ever. There is no traceback, as the exception is not thrown by python, but by the java app.

Comment: `communicate` should have a default `input=None`.  Even if it was sending garbage (unlikely) then that means that the child is reading `stdin`.    More likely the child is wanting some terminator (could also explain the Java exception).  What is the child process expecting on `stdin`?  You could try sending a newline or maybe an empty string.

Comment: `stdin` is not redirected! `.communicate()` sends nothing. if `java ... |& ...` works then the corresponding `Popen() + .communicate()` Python code should also work. I understand that it is java exception (`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` hints at that), post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: do you understand that without `.wait()`, `.communicate()` your Python code actually does not wait for the child process to finish?

Comment: "I however would like [...] the process to be blocking" - yes I understand I am not waiting for the child process to finish. And I *would like for that to be the case*. Hence the use of `communicate()`.

Comment: And yes, `java ... |& tee -a java.log` runs fine. Empty java.log

Comment: I meant without `.wait()` OR without `.communicate()` your parent Python script does not wait for the child process to finish. *Both* `.wait()` and `.communicate()` wait for the subprocess to complete. Does `subprocess.check_call(
    ["java", "-jar", "application.jar", "-outfile", "/path/to/outfile", "/path/to/infile"])` work? Does `output = subprocess.check_output(
    ["java", "-jar", "application.jar", "-outfile", "/path/to/outfile", "/path/to/infile"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` work? btw, why do you want to redirect stdout/stderr if `java` doesn't print anything (empty `java.log`)?

Comment: Sebastian, I really appreciate your input. But I *do* understand all of what your asking. I *would* like for my python to wait for the child process to finish. I *would* like to achieve that by means of `communicate()`. But that in turn makes the (2nd party) java app throw an exception. Whether I call `wait()`, `communicate()` or replace `Popen(...)` by `check_call(...)` or `check_output(...)` all has the same effect. It breaks the child process execution.

Comment: If `check_call()` doesn't work then the `java` program doesn't work in your environment. Because *the only* difference between `Popen()` and `check_call()` is that the latter **waits** for the child to finish and raises an exception for non-zero exit status. Calling `.wait()` has no effect on the running child -- none -- you can't break it. `.communicate()`  is a red-herring here. Create a command that works somewhere e.g., in a shell (with a proof that it works such as zero exit status, the expected output) then try to run it in Python.